# Debian: Cannot access opened port in US from EU

Tags: debian, socket

On debian 9 I have opened port 0.0.0.0:18000 using python 3, but I cannot access it from outside (*target machine actively refused it*). I have no firewalls.

I suspected that it might be because I'm using IPv4 and the server is in US while I'm trying to access it from EU via IPv4. But I tried IPv6 too and it's the same error message. I can normally access it via SSH over IPv4. Ports 80/443 also have normal access over IPv4 but it translates it into IPv6.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::18000                :::*                    LISTEN      701/python3
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      552/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      572/apache2
tcp6       0      0 MY_SERVER_IPv4:443      MY-PC-IPv4:10991      ESTABLISHED 61154/apache2
```

Interesting thing is that using putty I successfully connected using SSH over IPv4 (without translation).

```
tcp        0      0 MY_SERVER_IPv4:22       MY-PC-IPv4:17085      ESTABLISHED 57796/sshd: root@no
```

Does anybody have an idea what can I do?

Comment: You may not have a firewall on that particular machine, but there may still be a firewall between your EU and US system that lets through SSH traffic, but blocks requests to other ports.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thx for the tip, I'll check with my service provider.

Comment: I would probably start by running `nmap` against the target system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I checked with `nmap`:

```
nmap -p 18000 MY_SERVER_IP
```

and got:

```
STATE:
filtered
```

So I asked for control panel access and noticed that there is `Firewall Policies` of which I (because I'm inexperienced) wasn't aware of.

Problem solved. Thank you.